# Minimagick throwing an error after deployment to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, carrierwave, minimagick

I've uploaded my little project to Heroku and changed storage from file to fog and now this issue has arose thats got me stumped.

So when using the carrierwave uploader I have 2 methods inside

```
version :landscape, if: :is_landscape? do
  process resize_to_fit: [@land_height, 200]
end

version :portrait, if: :is_portrait? do
  process resize_to_fit: [200, @port_width]
end


def is_landscape? picture
  image = MiniMagick::Image.open(picture.path)
  width = image[:width]
  aspect = image[:width] / image[:height].to_f
  @land_height = aspect * width
  image[:width] > image[:height]
end

def is_portrait? picture
  image = MiniMagick::Image.open(picture.path)
  height = image[:height]
  aspect = image[:width] / image[:height].to_f
  @port_width = height / aspect
  image[:width] < image[:height]
end
```

The error is occuring when `Minimagick::Image.open` is being called. 
The error is =

> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - uploads/cover/image/12/p1.jpg

It looks like it's trying to find the image in my local storage to run the method on and not AWS.

I might add the original version of the image is being saved to AWS

As always any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing storage location. Try adding this under storage :file or uploader file

```
 def store_dir
   "uploads/logo/#{model.id}"
 end
```

then push code again on heroku.
It works for me.

Comment: def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end .             I have this storage location